# How to remove jsessionid from URL in my local Tomcat7 in Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have a java web app that I deploy in production with Tomcat7.
I use the `Tomcat Web Application Manager` page in production, where I deploy my WAR at the context path "/". In production I'm not seeing `jsessionid` in URL.

In my development environment though, the same application (hence the same `web.xml`), started with Tomcat7 inside eclipse is showing `jsessionid` in URL.

The only session configuration I have in my `web.xml` is:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The only difference I can see in both Tomcat7 is the `server.xml`:

Production:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Local:

```
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
    <Context docBase="MyApp" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyApp"  />
  </Host>
```

Another difference is that I use NGinx in production to do a proxy pass from port 80 to 8080 from Tomcat.

What may I be missing?

Thanks

Comment: i think if your client supports cookies, JSESSIONID will be put in cookies, otherwise it will automatically use URL parameter. Except you have disabled cookies in server.xml

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian so cookies might be somehow disabled right? But how? How can I fix my local Tomcat? Thanks

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Context path='/myApplicationContext' cookies='false'>
  <!-- other settings -->
</Context>
, you may accidentally added this in META-INF/context.xml file in your web application, or in context.xml in your config of tomcat folder

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian Yeah, I searched "cookies" in all my files, I haven't touched that :(  actually I just downloaded another Tomcat and set up again in ecplise... same thing.. thanks

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian comments are not a good place for code. If you have to, make it as short as possible (don't include code comments!) and use backticks to for inline code formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different browser for your development work than your production work? Or perhaps you set cookies in your browser to be disabled for this site? Or perhaps you are accessing it using some unit test framework rather than a browser?

Comment: Ok I will not do that, thank you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I use the same browser, Chrome. I could not find in chrome that the cookies are disabled. Tried with other browsers as well, same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for cookies to work properly, the domain name must have at least two dots (https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html).

So to make it work locally, I had to do the following:

Change the /etc/hosts file to include any domain name with at least one period, pointing to 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost.test
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Change the context.xml to include the new domain:

```
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".localhost.test" sessionCookiePath="/"> 
...
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may using a browser or other client that doesn't support (or disabled) cookies in your development environment.

Another Tip: you may use this code in tomcat 7 (in your web.xml file):

```
<session-config>
     <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried different browsers. All work for production, none work for my local. I tried to manually add an exception on Chrome to allow cookies on localhost, but it didn't work. About `tracking-mode` the `jsessionid` doesn't appear anymore.. but I'm looking the cookies, and the `jsessionid` changes for all requests. Which is not good.. it should be the same. Anyway, if I could keep my `web.xml` unchanged it would be good, because production is working great now.